# sharing Terraria-savegame on different mobile devices

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm looking forward to get Terraria for my android-devices and was wondering, if it's possible to share the same savegame (via DropBox, Google Drive, ...) with different android-devices, like a Smartphone and a Tablet. I'm not talking about mixing console-, PC- and mobile version saves. It's just about a pure mobile save. Is this possible and do I need a rooted device for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found in the official forums the world- and playerfiles are located in
**/data/data/com.and.games505.Terraria/files/** and **you need root**, to gain access to this directory.

For now I found no other way to get to your savegames.

Answer (score 0):

If putting a save from one device to another you may have to first create a save with the same names in the game then exit the game and copy and replace the 2 save files found in (Root/) data/data/com.and.games505.TerrariaPaid/files
The two you need to backup or replace are called ****.world and ****.player the stars will be what you named them.
This method works if the devices are different and they have different android versions.
This also fixes the CRASH on exit or when saving problem after copying over your saves files to another device or reloading them after a backup or update.